# Override Dagger2 Component / Module created with @Component.Factory

Tags: android, android-espresso, dagger-2

I'm trying to find the correct way to override a **Component** or **Module** within a Espresso test while using latest Dagger2 **@Component.Factory** features.
I have the following component definition:

```
@Component(
    modules = [SomeModule::class],
    dependencies = [SessionComponent::class]
)
interface MainComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(sessionComponent: SessionComponent): MainComponent
    }
}
```

and **SomeModule** definition it's:

```
@Module
object SomeModule {

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun some(): Some = SomeImpl()
}
```

**Some** it's an interface and **SomeImpl** will be it's implementation.

Now, to inject in our activity, we just do:

```
DaggerMainComponent.factory().create(sessionComponent).inject(this)
```

We resolve the **sessionComponent** with and extension function declared in our **CustomApp: Application**

```
val Context.sessionComponent: SessionComponent
    get() = App.sessionComponent(this)
```

Now as per recommendations in the official guide: https://dagger.dev/testing we should try to replace **MainComponent** with a **TestMainComponent** which will have a **TestSomeModule** with our test implementation.

My initial thoughts were in this direction:
Remove the injection from the activity and replaced it by an **Injector** object that will do it. Also, modify the **create()** method and pass the **Module**:

```
DaggerMainComponent.factory().create(sessionComponent).inject(this)
```

It's moved to:

```
object Injector {
   @VisibleForTesting
   var someModule: SomeModule = SomeModule()

    fun inject(activity: Activity) {
        when (activity) {
            is MainActivity -> {
                DaggerMainComponent.factory().create(App.sessionComponent(activity), someModule).inject(activity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the new **Factory** definition:

```
@Component.Factory
 interface Factory {
  fun create(sessionComponent: SessionComponent, someModule: SomeModule): MainComponent
 }
```

Then, after the **onCreate()** in the activity we just invoke `Injector.inject(this)`

The idea behind this was that in a UI Test we could do:

```
@Before
 fun setup() {
  Injector.someModule = TestSomeModule
 }
```

and change the implementation that way. It fails thought since **SomeModule** it's a singleton object and we cannot extend from it.

This lead me to the following approach:
The app has **release** and **debug** *buildTypes*. Within the release and debug folder I have the real implementation of the **Injector** (with **MainComponent** referencing **SomeModule**).
Then in the **androidTest** folder I have another **Injector** object but with the following:

```
object Injector {

    fun inject(activity: Activity) {
        when (activity) {
            is MainActivity -> {
                DaggerTestMainComponent.factory().create(App.sessionComponent(activity)).inject(activity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and **TestMainComponent** it's

```
@Component(
    modules = [TestSomeModule::class],
    dependencies = [SessionComponent::class]
)
interface TestMainComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(sessionComponent: SessionComponent): TestMainComponent
    }
}

@Module
object TestSomeModule {
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun greeter(): Some = TestSomeImpl()
}
```

This approach works and gradle replaces the **Injector** object from the debug folder with the one in the androidTest folder, however, I'm wondering if there's a better approach to avoid having to use two **Injector** objects for this purpose, or maybe just update the **Module** used with the test one.
Any advice it's welcome!